# How apply validation on text field with respect to value of another text filed?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, nsrange

I want to apply validation on text field. I have two text filed and i want to enter only 0-11 value when second text field value is equal to "AM". How apply validation text filed with respect to another text field's value?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

get the value from second textfiled and check then validate like

```
if([secTxtField.text isEqualToString:@"AM"])
{
  //do the validation for the first
}
```

first check for only numbers here,

```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
            static NSCharacterSet *charSet = nil;
            if(!charSet) {
                charSet = [[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet] retain];
            }
            NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
      if(!(location.location == NSNotFound))
    {
      if([secTxtField.text isEqualToString:@"AM"])
      {
          //get the first textField input
         //Conver to int
        //Check for less than 11 
        if (pass) 
        {
            return YES;
       }
       else
       {
          return NO;
       }
      }
    }
            return (location.location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Comment: how apply validation and where?

Comment: get the FirstTextField data , Convert it into int and check.Or check the string matching pattern and do

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your design by keeping references to both text fields in your view controller.

However, it would be much more conforming to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines to use a `UIPickerView` for choosing from a number of items less than 12.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(textField==self.txt1 && [self.txt2.text isEqualToString:@"AM"]){

        [self.txt1 setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    }
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if(textField==self.txt1 && [self.txt2.text isEqualToString:@"AM"]){

        int no=[self.txt1.text intValue];
        NSLog(@"%d",no);
        int enteredno=[string intValue];
        int sum=no*10+enteredno;
        if (sum>11) {
            return NO;
        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Here txt1 and txt2 are first and second textfields. Set the delegate to both the textfields.